# How to check if user actually started the android app, not just returned to the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, launching-application

How to distinguish the call of onCreate() on *actual start* of app or on switching activities of already started app and similar actions (like *returning* to  the app while it is not shut down)? 
I've already tried to check if savedInstanceState!=null, but it only works on screen rotation, not returning to the activity from another activity of this app or another app. I also tried to get/set a special variable in onRestoreInstanceState() and  onSaveInstanceState(), but it is not the solution for described cases.

How to implement this checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static boolean isFirstRun = true;

public void onCreate(...) {
    if (isFirstRun) {
        // do stuff
        isFirstRun = false;
    }
}
```

Did you try to do something like that?

Comment: Thank you, at first glance it works!  I didn't to tumble to this obvious solution)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case, is make your "default" `Activity` a basic launcher style `Activity`. Its only purpose is to launch your main `Activity`. When the launcher starts the main `Activity`, it can pass that fact through with a `Bundle`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("first_start", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The launcher `Activity` is defined in XML as having [noHistory](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist). That way, it will only be opened with the App is started for the first time.

```
<activity
    android:name=".LauncherActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I suspect this approach is slightly complicated: for simple check you should start additional activity, call putExtra().. Maybe add one static boolean (as proposed by ChriZzZ) is easier (if such idea has no pitfalls).

Comment: You should probably test and see what fits you better.